# Text Mesh Pro in if statement doesnt work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to program a code section in my game where you can type in rewards to get coins or other stuff and my problem is that the if statement in the InputField function doesnt work even thought i can Debug.Log the code.text, so i don't know what to do now.
Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string firstLevel;
    public string options;
    public TextMeshProUGUI code;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        
    }

    public void StartGame () {
        
        SceneManager.LoadScene(firstLevel);
    }

    public void ExitGame () {
        
        Application.Quit();
    }
    public void Options () {
        
        SceneManager.LoadScene(options);
    }
    public void InputField()
    {
        if(code.text == "Hello")
        {
            Debug.Log("works");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn’t work. What did do you do with that method?

Comment: In the end i want it to give me more coins.

Comment: Well that’s a whole new thing. What have you done with that method to make it respond to anything. There is not enough info to recreate your problem

Comment: I can try to explain it more in detail.

Comment: So There is and Input field and a button next to it and if you click on the button and the text that you wrote in the input field is equal to "Hello" in this case it should print "works".

Comment: and I assigned the Function Input Field to the Button